# Removing redundant escape as per recommended by Android Studio cause app to crash

Tags: android, regex, unit-testing

I have regex as below

```
object MyRegtest {
    val TEST = Pattern.compile("\\{[^{}]+\\}")
}
```

Android Studio says I have a redundant escape.

After removing them as per recommended by Android Studio, it became as below

```
object MyRegtest {
    val TEST = Pattern.compile("\\{[^{}]+}")
}
```

It seems all good, as when I run my unit test it compiles and run fine. Note it compile fine before and after changes

```
    @Test
    fun addition_isCorrect() {
        val matcher = MyRegtest.TEST.matcher("2 matches {GoOd} and {GrEaT}, not {} to catch")
        while (matcher.find()) {
            println(matcher.group())
        }
    }
```

When compile and run the App (simple sample)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val matcher = MyRegtest.TEST.matcher("2 matches {GoOd} and {GrEaT}, not {} to catch")
        while (matcher.find()) {
            Log.d("Testing", matcher.group())
        }
    }
}
```

It will crash

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 9
    \{[^{}]+}
```

If I put back the original regex, the compiles app, and test works fine.

Did I do something wrong, or is this a bug recommendation from Android Studio? Why is the recommended optimized regex only works on unit test, and crash on the app?

Comment: I have filed an issue to google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167122876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android regex, you need to escape the closing curly brace outside a character class, otherwise, the pattern becomes invalid (the `Syntax error in regexp pattern` error is shown then as expected).

The notification you get from the Android Studio is most likely based on Java regex flavor, where the `}` char does not have to be escaped outside a character class.

So, in this case, Android Studio is wrong when notifying of a "redundant escape", it is not redundant in Android regex context.

Comment: It's 2022, this issue is still present in Kotlin and we're forced to add `@Suppress("RegExpRedundantEscape")` just to get rid of that annoying false warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try using quotes to escape your characters.

For example: `\\QA+1+B\\E`

Where **\Q** indicates that all characters up to **\E** needs to be escaped and **\E** means we need to end the escaping that was started with **\Q**. This just means that whatever is in between **\Q** and **\E** would be escaped.

Click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-regexp-escape-char#:%7E:text=%5CQ%20indicates%20that%20all%20characters,regular%20expression%20provided%20to%20it.) to learn more.